# List defining the list of variable of function in Python

Tags: python, function

I want to have a function `foo`  which outputs another function, whose list of variables depends on an input list.

Precisely:

Suppose `func` is a function with the free variable `t` and three parameters `A,gamma,x`

Example: `func = lambda t,A,gamma,x: Somefunction`

I want to define a function `foo`, which takes as input a list and outputs another function. The output function is a sum of `func`'s, where each `func` summand has his parameters independent from each other.

Depending on the input list the variables of the outputs changes in the following:

If the entry of the list is 'None' then the output function 'gains' a variable and if the entry of the list is a float it 'fixes' the parameter.

Example:

```
li=[None,None,0.1]
g=foo(li)
```

gives the same output as

`g = lambda t,A,gamma: func(t,A,gamma,0.1)`

or

```
li=[None,None,0.1,None,0.2,0.3]
g=foo(li)
```

gives the same output as

`g = lambda t,A1,gamma1,A2:func(t,A,gamma,0.1)+func(t,A2,0.2,0.3)`

Note: the order in the list is relevant and this behaviour is wanted.

I don't have any clue on how to do that...

I first tried to build a string, which depends on the inout list and then to execute it, but this is surely not the way.

Comment: This is fairly abstract...Are you trying to build currying in python?

Comment: See: [funcy.curry](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/funcs.html#curry)

Comment: Will `func` always have three parameters?

Comment: It seems like you're basically looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried to implement so far?

Comment: @JamesMills The string generator is awful and I will spare you that :-) Could you elaborate on curry a little bit ?

Comment: What are the `A`s? Where do they come from?

Comment: @ThomasProduit wat? What string generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, partition the parameters from `li` into chunks. Then use an iterator to either get the `next` from the function parameters `*args`, if the value in that chunk is `None`, or the provided value from the parameters chunk.

```
def foo(li, func, num_params):
    chunks = (li[i:i+num_params] for i in range(0, len(li), num_params))
    def function(t, *args):
        result = 0
        iter_args = iter(args)
        for chunk in chunks:
            actual_params = [next(iter_args) if x is None else x for x in chunk]
            result += func(t, *actual_params)
        return result
    return function
```

Example:

```
def f(t, a, b, c):
    print t, a, b, c
    return a + b + c

func = foo([1,2,None,4,None,6], f, 3)
print func("foo", 3, 5)
```

Output:

```
foo 1 2 3  # from first call to f
foo 4 5 6  # from second call to f
21         # result of func
```

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to implement this with functools.partial?

Comment: @NeoWang Not sure, maybe, but AFAIK, if you fix the first parameter with `partial`, then you have to use named parameters for the others, e.g. `f_part(t, z=3)`. This might actually make it even _more_ complicated.